# Get result of internet traffic monitor for particular period in ubuntu server

Tags: server, internet

`Nginx` is serving webpages from ubuntu server. Once or twice in a week I get warning mail from the cloud server provider says `The amount of transferred data has exceeded the limit:`

```
The amount of transferred data has exceeded the limit:

hourly: (1:00 - 02:00)

IP / Subnet     Server name  Limit (MB)   Traffic (MB)
xx.xx.xx.xxx      Niren        200          238.264
```

So I want to monitor the internet traffic in ubuntu server for particular period say with the above warning I want to know how the traffic exceed the limit in specified time duration(1hr-2hr). I want to know what are the IP's trying to access server in that duration.

**Additional info:**

Cloud server provider: `Hetzner`, Server OS: `Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal`, Web server: `Nginx`.

**update:** I tried [vnstat](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/330/Monitoring_your_bandwidth_usage_with_vnstat) but it shows hourly, weekly, daily or monthly traffic details, but I wanted to know what are the IP's tried to access server in specific duration this is not possible with vnstat.

Comment: Nginx certainly creates detailed logs which probably contain all you want to know. Take a look at the `/var/log` folder.